# EF4 Self referencing with association 0..1 -> 1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, data-modeling

There's a lot of reading on self referencing problems, but I can't seem to find an answer to my question.

Say I have a **Human**(A), and I want A to have a partner, another Human(B). Naturally, it means that B has a partner in human A. How would you solve this? Ideally, I should only have to do:

```
humanA.Partner = humanB;
```

and humanB would automatically get humanA as a partner.

I would have thought I could create a Human enity, and add an Association, something like:

> **End1** Entity:*Human*, Multiplicity:*0..1*, Navigation Property:*Partner*
>
> **End2** Entity:*Human*, Multiplicity:*0..1*

So, each human has zero or one Partner which is a human.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1:0..1 mapping is possible only when [entities "share" primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761362/entity-framework-one-to-one-mapping-issues). It means when the related's entity FK is also its PK. So self referencing 1:0..1 cannot exist. I think you can't even map it in database directly.

Comment: Both entities do share the same key (both Human entities). Partner is simply the navigation property name.

Comment: @Morten: No they don't. In this type of relation they have to share PK value - obviously you can have two entities with same PK value in one table.